# mask won't scale in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have two movies and a simple .png as mask (which is just a white circle).

The first movie has a mask modifier like this:

[image]

The result is perfect, exactly as i wanted:

[image]

But now i wanted to animate the .png (the circle) and i tried to animate the scale values of my .png strip.

like this:

[image]

unfortunately that didn't work.

What did i make wrong? or how could i achieve this? Yes, i think, if i made an animated mask where the circle is getting bigger, this would work (i never tried), but i hoped for the lazy way where i could just scale my .png :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mask doesnt scale in VSE because you are not using PNG as a mask.

---

From the screen it seems you have under *Image editor > MASK* (curve mask) of the same name ...

[image]

... that is participating in your modifier (according to highlighted  "Mask" option in your screen). To use PNG you have to switch Mask modifier to **STRIP**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just to the right of the text entry for Scale X is a diamond that means the current frame is keyed. Check the Diamond after setting the value on your start and end frame and the scale should animate as you’d expect.

If that doesn’t work pls attach your blend file (with images packed) or a zip and we’ll take a look.

Comment: this is right, but as you can see: the scale field is green (which means: it is already keyframed). And on the timeline you can see two keyframes.